# Node library (created in TS): Correct way to export avoiding duplicates - ready for publishing?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Can anyone help?

I just created a node library that I want to publish to npm - currently, I am testing it locally.

I have 2 directories that present models, these 2 directories have unique files but there are a few files where the name is the same i.e. meta-data.ts, requirements.ts  - These files are automatically generated and although now these 2 files are the same across the 2 directories - they could diverge in the future.

My libraries are compiled to js and placed in a /dist directory and then in the root i am doing

```
export * "./models/red"
export * "./models/blue"
```

but this isn't possible as there are files the same.

the structure of the package that would be published would be

```
\ 
  index.js
  dist
    models
      red
       ..files
      blue
       ..files
```

Now I can't really import them from the subdirectories on publishing because that means that in production I would have to import ( not in the same place)

```
  import {MetaData} packagename/dist/models/red

  import {MetaData} packagename/dist/models/blue
```

Hence I would need to include the dist folder in there and while developing locally this dist does not exist - and also the dist is the compiled files.

Also including the dist on the import just doesn't seem right

So I am wondering if I am doing this correctly and what my options are?

I thought I had to EXPORT all files from the root that I want my package to expose?

Also, there is no syntax for "exporting "as"

I don't want to rename my models, they should co-exist.

Of course, if I was importing the files locally without going through a package then I would not have this problem as i could import them relatively from the models

```
  import {MetaData} ./models/red

  import {MetaData} ./models/blue
```